# How to implement "over (partition by value)" using Spark Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I am planning to modify a column of Spark Dataframe to implement similar purpose of the following Hive QL:

```
SELECT Id, MIN(Id) over (PARTITION BY Age) Rep FROM Employees
```

My question is how to implement "over (partition by ..)" in UDF?

My call is like this:

```
def _udfuntion = { ... }
val ownfunc = udf(_udfunction)
df.withColumn("Rep", ownfunc($"Id", $"Age"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a User Defined Aggregate Function (UDAF) rather than a UDF.

There are some great examples out there, for example https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udaf-scala.html
and 
https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-sql-UserDefinedAggregateFunction.html